# Alfresco maxLength Adhoc Workflow

Tags: forms, user-interface, workflow, alfresco

I tried to increase the character limit for the Adhoc Wactiviti (Workflow) which offers the Alfresco Community Edition 5.0 by default. I added the following line to the Adhoc's "control" block which is inside the share-workflow-form-config.xml:

```
<control-param name="maxLength">1024</control-param>
```

The control block now looks like this:

```
<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
  <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
  <control-param name="maxLength">1024</control-param>
</control>
```

I restarted everything after I changed the file but unfortunately the field is still limited to 250 characters.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**Two things to make sure here.**

1) You are pointing to right config block because you have not mentioned which task form or workflow form you are trying to override. 
For Instance to overrider adhoc workflow form you need to override this config.

```
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$activitiAdhoc">
```

So, if you are point to wrong config it will never reflect.

2) You are point to right property.Each control is tied to one property so changes which you do will reflect for that property only. You have not mentioned that as well here.

Based on combination of above two things it will reflect the changes.